# How do I get the position of a result in the list after an order_by?

Tags: python, sql, django, rank

I'm trying to find an efficient way to find the rank of an object in the database related to it's score. My naive solution looks like this:

```
rank = 0
for q in Model.objects.all().order_by('score'):
  if q.name == 'searching_for_this'
    return rank
  rank += 1
```

It should be possible to get the database to do the filtering, using order_by:

Model.objects.all().order_by('score').filter(name='searching_for_this')

But there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the index for the order_by step after the filter.

Is there a better way to do this? (Using python/django and/or raw SQL.)

My next thought is to pre-compute ranks on insert but that seems messy.

Comment: something like: 1. `select score as retrieved_score where name='searching_for_this'` 2. `select count(*) where score <= retrieved_score` -> rank

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in one database query using Django ORM. But if it doesn't bothers you, I would create a custom method on a model:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class Model(models.Model):
    score = models.IntegerField()
    ...

    def ranking(self):
        count = Model.objects.filter(score__lt=self.score).count()
        return count + 1
```

You can then use "ranking" anywhere, as if it was a normal field:

```
print Model.objects.get(pk=1).ranking
```

**Edit:** This answer is from 2010. Nowadays I would recommend [Carl's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317266/262618) instead.

Comment: Thanks. Note that in the example you gave, the order was ascending (in other words "the lower the score, the higher the ranking"), so I went with it. If higher score should actually increase the ranking you should change "score__lt" to "score__gt".

Comment: This should be computationally expensive, as it will run the ranking aggregate query for each row in `Model.objects.all()`

Comment: @mehmet Yes, of course. That's what I was trying to say in the first paragraph of this post. Back then (6 years ago) there wasn't a more effective way to do this using Django ORM. Nowadays there might be a PostgreSQL only solution using PostgreSQL window functions and a custom annotate function. I might look into that when I have more time.

Answer (score 13):

Using the [new Window functions in Django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) you could write it like this...

```
from django.db.models import Sum, F
from django.db.models.expressions import Window
from django.db.models.functions import Rank

Model.objects.filter(name='searching_for_this').annotate(
            rank=Window(
                expression=Rank(),
                order_by=F('score').desc()
            ),
        )
```

Comment: This is great, my only issue is when I do more filtering after the queryset it's not keeping the rank. Like I'm getting all results ranking them, and then filtering by username the result is ranked against that smaller queryset not the whole.

Comment: How I resolved it might not be the best solution, is I've created a helper dictionary from a global queryset, for user id and rank, and for displaying actual rank I'm using the helper dictionary instead adding rank to the filtered queryset.

Comment: is it working on MySQL 5.7 aurora version? Any Idea

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this:

```
obj = Model.objects.get(name='searching_for_this')
rank = Model.objects.filter(score__gt=obj.score).count()
```

You can pre-compute ranks and save it to Model if they are frequently used and affect the performance.

Answer (score 2):

In "raw SQL" with a standard-conforming database engine (PostgreSql, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2, ...), you can just use the SQL-standard `RANK` function -- but that's not supported in popular but non-standard engines such as MySql and Sqlite, and (perhaps because of that) Django does not "surface" this functionality to the application.

Comment: Ah, I'm testing on Sqlite before deployment to PGSQL.

Comment: @BobBob, if you want, you could run a small local instance of PostgreSql for testing purposes -- it's neither hard nor onerous.