# Finding the Position of a certain record in the Query in DJango ORM

Tags: django, orm

I have a model of Django like this,

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    ratings = models.FloatField(default=1000)
```

What I want to do is the person who's logged in, I want to find his `rank` based upon the user's ratings. So, that is, I need to find the Position of the specified row in a query where the records will be ordered by the `ratings` column, in descending order.

I found a good solution here but it is unfortunately not working for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317266/11454905

Using this same concept, I typed this query,

```
player = Account.objects.filter(user = request.user).annotate(rank = Window(expression=Rank(), order_by=F('ratings').desc()),)[0]
```

But no matter what user is, it always returns `player.rank` as `1`, which is not true. I fail to understand what am I doing wrong and how can I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for just a single User object, then you can just count the Users that have a rating higher than the current user - I note that you are using `filter(user=request.user)` which doesn't actually get a single user object. Generally speaking, you should use `get()`, although here you can just do `request.user`.

```py
rank = Player.objects.filter(ratings__gte=request.user.ratings).count()
```

As to annotating a queryset of users, you can use `Window()` and `DenseRank()` expressions:

```py
from django.db.models import Window
from django.db.models.functions import DenseRank

players = Player.objects.order_by('ratings').annotate(
    rank=Window(
        expression=DenseRank(),
        order_by=F('ratings').desc()
    )
)
```